# MomentJS issue on remote server

Tags: node.js, momentjs, sequelize.js

I get an issue with MomentJS on my remote server.

```
WARN: 'Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.'
```

It works perfectly on my local server but I get this message on my remote server...

I used SequelizeJS with NodeJS to manage my database and the issue is on the "createdAt" column of my table.

Comment: Do you have the same version of moment locally and remotely ?

Comment: Are you sure that the same date is provided to moment.js on both servers?  If I read the referenced issues content correctly, it means that, on your remote server, the date you are providing to moment's parser is not ISO.  Could some difference between your local & remote setups explain the difference? Can you print in both cases and show us the result ? It would also be nice to see how `createdAt` is filled in ...